How to Append MP4 Chunks to a Single Blob in Azure Blob Storage Without Playback Issues?
I’m building a service using the MediaRecorder API to record a user’s webcam media stream. For compatibility, I’m using the MIME type video/mp4; codecs=avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2 which supports recording and playback in both Chrome and Safari.
To prevent loss of recorded footage in case of unexpected interruptions (e.g., browser crash, power shutdown), I plan to upload each recorded chunk to Azure Blob Storage every second.
However, I want to manage the recording as a single video blob instead of creating multiple blobs for each start/stop of the recording session, simulating the feel of a single, uninterrupted video file. To achieve this, I’m considering using an append blob in Azure.
The issue is that this approach may result in playback issues due to metadata or timestamp conflicts within the merged chunks on Azure.
How can I resolve this problem?
(Note: I’m aware that tools like ffmpeg or mp4box can easily merge video files, but I'd prefer to avoid using wasm-based solutions due to their dependency on the client’s computing power. I’d also rather not implement a dedicated server for merging mp4 files, as that would be my last resort.)

Have you check this link

@Sampath First of all, thank you for your response.
However, the method you suggested seems to be valid only at the initial start/stop of the recording, doesn't it? In a situation where an mp4 file already exists in Azure Blob Storage due to a previous recording start/stop, appending a new blob through another recording start/stop will ultimately result in multiple sets of metadata overlapping within a single mp4 file.

what type of  playback issues  you are facing

To prevent overlapping metadata issues when appending new recordings to an existing MP4 file in Azure Storage, you can retrieve the blob’s properties and metadata, then check if a recording already exists. This approach allows you to append to the existing metadata instead of overwriting it.
Finally, to add new data to the existing MP4 file, you can follow this approach.
I referred to this link for managing properties and metadata in Azure Storage.
Below is the code to retrieve the existing metadata from the blob and check for an existing recording:
async function getBlobMetadata(blobClient) {
  const properties = await blobClient.getProperties();
  return properties.metadata;  
}

To append new metadata to an existing recording:
async function appendRecordingMetadata(blobClient, newMetadata) {
  const existingMetadata = await getBlobMetadata(blobClient);

The following code appends new data to the existing MP4 file:
 const mergedMetadata = { ...existingMetadata, ...newMetadata };


 await blobClient.setMetadata(mergedMetadata);
}

Below code is to append new data  to the existing MP4 file
async function appendRecordingToBlob(blobClient, newRecordingData) {
  const existingBlobData = await blobClient.downloadToBuffer(); 
  const updatedBlobData = Buffer.concat([existingBlobData, newRecordingData]); 

  await blobClient.upload(updatedBlobData, updatedBlobData.length);
}


For recording, I referred to this MediaStream Recording API guide and the MediaRecorder API documentation.
Below code to append MP4 chunks to a single blob in Azure Blob Storage:

async function appendToBlob(chunkPath, blobName) {
    const appendBlobClient = containerClient.getAppendBlobClient(blobName);
    
   
    const exists = await appendBlobClient.exists();
    if (!exists) {
    
        await appendBlobClient.create();
    }
    
    const chunkBuffer = fs.readFileSync(chunkPath);
   
    await appendBlobClient.appendBlock(chunkBuffer, chunkBuffer.length);
    console.log(`Appended chunk to blob: ${chunkPath}`);






Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.
However, the metadata I was referring to was specifically for the MP4 format, such as codec information, playback duration, and resolution.
I am aware that the Media Recorder API allows recording in segments for a single MP4 file using the pause/resume methods, but it seems this is only effective with the same MediaRecorder instance.

Therefore, in situations where it's not possible to maintain the same MediaRecorder instance (e.g., browser crash, power shutdown), I tried recording separately using the start/stop methods and merging them as you suggested. However, I encountered the following playback issues:
Timestamps do not function properly in video media players.
The video suddenly fast-forwards during playback.
It is impossible to set the playback time.
The main issue seems to be the duplication of metadata within a single MP4 file.

Please refer to the links below to check this: 30-second video that plays smoothly and 50-second video with playback issues (an additional 20 seconds recorded onto the above video)

Use tools like FFmpeg for Merging. Refer to this link for more details.
